# How to run findbugs automatically in maven on install

Tags: java, maven-2, findbugs

It's easy to add the [findbugs plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.0.1/usage.html) to maven so that it will run if I do

```
mvn site
```

However, I would like it to run whenever I do

```
mvn install
```

just like unit tests. That is, I don't want the install to succeed if findbugs finds any bugs. Is there are way for me to do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

About the [findbugs:check](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.0.1/check-mojo.html) goal, the documentation writes:

> Fail the build if there were any FindBugs violations in the source code. An XML report is put out by default in the target directory with the errors. To see more documentation about FindBugs' options, please see the FindBugs Manual.

So this is precisely the goal you're looking for. You now just have to bind the *check* goal to the <strike>*install*</strike> *verify* phase (the *verify* phase occurs just before *install* and is actually made to *run any checks to verify the package is valid and meets quality criteria* so I think it's a better choice):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <effort>Max</effort>
          <threshold>Low</threshold>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal> 
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Of course, adapt the configuration to suit your needs.

Comment: Url is broken, but it's accessible from [web-archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20090705143442/http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.0.1/check-mojo.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            ...
        </configuration>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[findbugs:check goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.0.1/check-mojo.html)

[findbugs: Violation Checking](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/2.0.1/examples/violationChecking.html)